# How Do I Parse A Date String Without minutes Using Moment.js

Tags: jquery, parsing, momentjs

I have a French date that has special characters in it, `à` and `h`. My sort works without the characters. When the characters are added to the date string the sort breaks.This is how the date should look:

```
"Mercredi, 4 Novembre à 9 h"
```

Here is how the date is outputted:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment("dddd, MMMM D H:mm", 'fr'); //  "Mercredi, 4 Novembre à 9 h"
```

I've tried this to no avail:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment("dddd, MMMM [à] D H [h]:mm", 'fr');
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have been able to get the sort to work in French but only if there are minutes. Unfortunately some of the output data is just the hour with no minutes. If there are no minutes included with the string the sort doesn't work. I can get around this by adding 00 if no minutes are available but this is not how the data should be displayed. Is there anyway parse and format the string if there are no minutes? example with minutes: Jeudi, 19 Novembre à 9 h 45 and without: Jeudi, 19 Novembre à 9 h

Answer (score 1):

the first parameter for moment is the date that you want, 2nd is the format you want to parse it through, then it takes the optional 3rd parameter of your locale, after pass this you have to format your date to get the final output.

is should be something like this

have a look at the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lotf9sed/)

```
  var a = moment('10/11/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'fr').format('dddd,D MMMM [à] H [h]');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I didn't phrase that properly. The characters are being output as part of the string from the DB. I just need to parse it properly so that the moment.js sort will work correctly. As of now the characters bork the sort.

Comment: The problem I am experiencing now, is the sort on the minutes. Some strings contain minutes and others do not. We could have 00 outputted if there are no minutes. Is there a way to sort on minutes if there are no characters? eg Mercredi, 4 Novembre à 9 h vs. Mercredi, 4 Novembre à 9 h 45 thanks